# ".btn.active" vs ".btn:active" in Bootstrap core CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap core CSS or similar style sheets, what is the role of `.btn.active` that comes after `.btn:active`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:active of .btn:active is a CSS selector that is active whenever the user is clicking the button.

.active of .btn.active is a CSS class bootstrap usually adds with JavaScript. It is to achieve slightly different behaviour than what the browser does. For example when you click a button and a menu opens, that might counter as the button still being active, but the browser does not see it as active.